# Xamarin.Forms Flexlayout Control with inside ContentView error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to center some controls on the screen and I'm using a FlexLayout control for that as the main container on the page and I set the following props Direction="Column" AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="Center" and it all works well until a add a control that is on another file (ContentView)
***Page

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<FlexLayout Direction="Column" AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="Center">
    <Button Text="Try It Out" Command="{Binding VibrateCommand}"></Button>
    <StackLayout>
        <controls:ErrorsList BindingContext="{Binding ErrorMessages}"></controls:ErrorsList>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

***ContentView (controls:ErrorList)

```
<ContentView>
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="..."  />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

***Result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zunuo.png)

Comment: Which effect did you want？

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the `Button` and `ListView` all in the center . You can use Grid with two Rows .

```
<Grid >

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
     <Button Text="Try It Out" HeightRequest="40" ></Button>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
     <controls:ErrorsList BindingContext="{Binding ErrorMessages}"></controls:ErrorsList>
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```